# How To Loop through result.invocationResult.resultSet in IBM worklight

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Everything works except the display function . In this display function i am trying to access the field Name from the resultSet but it is not working.

```
function succ(result)
    {   

        alert("connected");
        var a = result.invocationResult.resultSet[1].Name;
        $("#fetcharr").val(a);
        alert("connectedlll");
        display(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
        alert("the end");


    }
```

Display function is:

```
function display(items)
    {

        alert("heelo");
        for(var j in items )
        {
                var a = j.Name;
                alert(a);

        }

    }
```

Comment: This isn't Java. Kindly use the correct tag.

Comment: it would be better to debug if you provide the `resultSet` which you are receiving in onScuess

Comment: @user3763296, If my answer helped you solve this issue, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Why the need for two functions here?
Anyway, to loop through the resultSet you can use a `for` loop like so:

```
function succ(result) {   
    for (var i = 0; i < result.invocationResult.resultSet.length; i++) {
        display(result.invocationResult.resultSet[i]);
        // do something with the current result, for example:
        $("#someIdInTheHTML").append("<p>Name: " + result[i].name + "</p>");
    };
}
```

You will want to search through the "worklight-adapters" tag, as this has been asked many times in various forms.